# DELETE all documents of a type in ElasticSearch 2.x

Tags: elasticsearch

I've updated ElasticSearch to 2.1 version.

Before of that, I deleted every document in a type using:

```
curl -XDELETE '<server_node>:<port>/<index>/<type>' -i
curl -XDELETE 'http://ESNode01:9201/living/inputs' -i
```

From now then, this is the response:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
>
> Content-Length: 61
>
> No handler found for uri [/living/inputs] and method [DELETE]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deleting a mapping type is [not supported anymore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_types_may_no_longer_be_deleted) since 2.0.

If you just need to delete the documents, then you may use the [delete by query plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/plugins-delete-by-query.html), otherwise you should create a new index without the mapping you want to delete and reindex your data.

Comment: I've installed the plugin. After reboot ES, I've been able to perform: `curl -XDELETE '<index>/<type>/_query' -i -d ' { "query": { "match_all": {} } }'` and the documents were deleted. However, I need the last thing you've just commented. I need to apply another mapping and reindex that (I open another question!)

Comment: However, I believe, I should have to need to be able to remove a index... Does it really not possible?

Comment: Removing an index is definitely possible, `curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/index` and you're good. That will remove the index and all mapping types of that index. This is the second option I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I need to remove only a type... Sorry for the miswriting.

Comment: You just said index in your second comment :-) Then no, back to my answer, removing only a type is not possible in ES 2.0 onward.

Comment: How do you create the new index and reindex the data?

Comment: Without the plugin I get routing_missing_exception. Is there no other way to delete the documents of type without any plugin?